# Can't get a file from amazon s3 storage using curl with query string requestauthentication

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to download a file from my s3 storage using simple bash script that I found on Internet.

```
#!/bash/sh

bucket='my_bucket_name'
file_path='path_to_my_file'
resource="/${bucket}/${file_path}"
# set url time to expire

expires=$(date +%s -d '4000 seconds')
stringtoSign="GET\n\n\n${expires}\n${resource}"
s3Key='s3Key_here'
s3Secret='s3SecretKey_here'

signature=`echo -en ${stringtoSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Key} -binary | base64`


curl -G https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file_path} \
    --data AWSAccessKeyId=${s3Key} \
    --data Expires=${expires}\
    --data-urlencode Signature=${signature}
```

As you can see nothing special here. I want to use variant with a query string request.

But it always sends me back '403 Forbidden' error with additional message - "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." Googling that error message didn't help me too.

I checked credentials with a help of boto python library,

```
import boto

from boto.s3.key import Key


KEY_ID = 'key_id'
SECRET_KEY_ID = 'secret_key'
SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'path_to_file'
DEST_FILE_NAME = 'file'
BUCKET_NAME = 'my_bucket_name'

boto.set_stream_logger('boto')
conn = boto.connect_s3(KEY_ID, SECRET_KEY_ID)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

# Get the Key object of the given key, in the bucket
k = Key(bucket, SOURCE_FILE_NAME)

# Get the contents of the key into a file
k.get_contents_to_filename(DEST_FILE_NAME)
```

just entered two secret keys I got, bucket name and path to file and it worked for me. But this is not what I'm looking for.

Of course, I read this [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheAuthenticationHeader) and tried to follow it. My 'stringtoSing' variable is formed in right way. I just can't imagine where mistake is hidding.

Comment: It would probably be much easier just to use the [aws cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) `aws s3 cp s3://bucket/key local/file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set all variables names in right places and updated openssl to OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016. Now it works.

Comment: Also make sure your .sh file is executable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Key}
```

You don't sign with your key -- you sign with your secret.

```
openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret}
```

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for you answer. I copy-pasted from variable name while I was writing this post. Anyway it doesn't change anything.  But what helped me **it's updating openssl** on my laptop. Now it seems to work.

Comment: That's odd, since the function you're using in openssl is a pretty primitive one.  Do you happen to remember the old version you were running?

Comment: unfortunately I don't remember. But I can check it out tomorrow. If it's needed.

Comment: Not necessarily needed, but if there's a bug in an old version of openssl, it might be useful for future visitors.    That is the purpose of Stack Overflow -- it's not about solving any individual programmer's immediate, individual problems.  It's about solving problems and making the solutions available in a well-moderated environment where we attempt to provide useful answers and keep the noise level down so that other programmers can find those solutions when they encounter the same problems in the future. If we can't explain how/why on a question or answer, it's of limited value to others.

Comment: On my work station `openssl is 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`. But in this case it was my ridiculous mistake. I forgot to make my .sh script executable. `sudo chmod +x script.sh` is needed to be done also.