# Download AWS S3 file from EC2 instance

Tags: curl, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've a script to download file from AWS S3 and it works from a separate server outside of AWS. But when I put this script on an EC2 instance and tried it then it returns error "SignatureDoesNotMatch - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

But it works on the other server. The ec2 is on the same region as the s3 host. I'm guessing it has something to do with the host. I tried these host/url but it returns the same error.

Anyone able to download s3 files from ec2 with curl? I need to use only curl. Please answer if you know how to do it through curl. Thanks.

https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/$bucket/$file

https://s3.amazonaws.com/$bucket/$file

https://$bucket.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/$file

https://$bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/$file

```
#!/bin/sh
file="file-name"
bucket="bucket-name"
resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
dateValue="`date +'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'`"
stringToSign="GET\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
s3Secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
signature=$(echo -en "${stringToSign}" | openssl sha1 -hmac "${s3Secret}" -binary | base64)
curl -H "Host: s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com" \
 -H "Date: $dateValue" \
 -H "Content-Type: $contentType" \
 -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
 https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/$bucket/$file -o $file
```

Comment: [We've seen a question here like this before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39921825/1695906), presumably related to a bug in OpenSSL, because it was resolved by an upgrade of OpenSSL.  Unfortunately, the old version wasn't identifiable so the underlying cause was never identified.  Perhaps comparing OpenSSL versions on the two machines would be a starting point for you.

Comment: Hi Michael, I just tried a higher openssl ver. The one in the servers that outside of aws and worked has OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 and then now aws server has OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016 but it still returns SignatureDoesNotMatch. I'm wondering if it could be I'm not using the correct host or url?

Comment: It seems maybe my above code works for centos. I tried another ubuntu server and it doesn't work. Maybe somehow the line for generate the signature not processed properly for ubuntu. I tried the latest openssl version but seems still not work.

Comment: Curiosity: change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: ubuntu using a different echo than centos echo -en ${stringToSign } literally prints out dash space e n space G E T slash n ...

Answer (score 3):

Rather than writing a CURL command, consider using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

It has a `aws s3 cp` command that can copy content to/from Amazon S3 buckets (and even between buckets).

Comment: Hi. I know there're other options but as I mentioned I need to use curl so I'm hoping answer about what I asked. I'm using autoscale so I already have image created and there will be alot to do for all regions to set up the CLI. I've chef running so it's easier that I load some bash code through cookbook to run the download without updating the image.

Comment: Please answer if you know how to do it through curl instead of suggesting other options. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
#!/bin/sh
S3_KEY='/file.txt'
S3_SECRET_KEY='xxx'
S3_ACCESS_KEY='AKIAxxx'
S3_HOST=yourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com

AMZ_DATE=$(date -u "+%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
DATE=$(/bin/echo ${AMZ_DATE} | cut -b 1-8)
REGION=ap-southeast-1
CANONICAL_REQUEST="GET\n${S3_KEY}\n\nhost:${S3_HOST}\nx-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD\nx-amz-date:${AMZ_DATE}\n\nhost;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date\nUNSIGNED-PAYLOAD"
STRING_TO_SIGN="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n${AMZ_DATE}\n${DATE}/${REGION}/s3/aws4_request\n$(/bin/echo -en ${CANONICAL_REQUEST} | sha256sum | cut -f 1 -d' ')"

AWS_SIG_V4_AND_S3_SECRET_KEY=AWS4${S3_SECRET_KEY}

DATE_HMAC_HEX=$(/bin/echo -n "${DATE}" | openssl sha256 -hmac "${AWS_SIG_V4_AND_S3_SECRET_KEY}" | cut -f 2 -d' ')
DATE_HMAC_BIN=$(/bin/echo -n "${DATE_HMAC_HEX}" | xxd -r -p)

REGION_HMAC_HEX=$(/bin/echo -n "${REGION}"  | openssl sha256 -hmac "${DATE_HMAC_BIN}" | cut -f 2 -d' ')
REGION_HMAC_BIN=$(/bin/echo -n "${REGION_HMAC_HEX}" | xxd -r -p)

SERVICE_HMAC_HEX=$(/bin/echo -n "s3"  | openssl sha256 -hmac "${REGION_HMAC_BIN}" | cut -f 2 -d' ')
SERVICE_HMAC_BIN=$(/bin/echo -n "${SERVICE_HMAC_HEX}" | xxd -r -p)

SIGNING_KEY_HEX=$(/bin/echo -n "aws4_request"  | openssl sha256 -hmac "${SERVICE_HMAC_BIN}" | cut -f 2 -d' ')
SIGNING_KEY_BIN=$(/bin/echo -n "${SIGNING_KEY_HEX}" | xxd -r -p)


SIGNATURE_HEX=$(/bin/echo -ne "${STRING_TO_SIGN}" | openssl sha256 -hmac "${SIGNING_KEY_BIN}" | cut -f 2 -d' ')

curl -vv https://${S3_HOST}/file.txt \
    -H "Host: ${S3_HOST}" \
    -H "x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD" \
    -H "x-amz-date: ${AMZ_DATE}" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${S3_ACCESS_KEY}/${DATE}/${REGION}/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=${SIGNATURE_HEX}"
```

This is using AWS Signature V4.
I have tested this and it works on both CentOS 7.3 and Ubuntu LTS 16.04 for my bucket in ap-southeast-1 region.
I would highly suggest using John Rotenstein's suggestion.

Comment: I've been trying to get this work for hours. Thank you for this. I followed aws docs and had no idea what's not working. apparently I missed two things: I used hash of empty string instead of `UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD`, and while generating signing key - I didn't convert to binary. Those steps apparently necessary, and are not mentioned in the docs

Comment: Any idea why sometimes it returns 403 with `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method` ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Titi Wangsa bin Damhore was very helpful. This is a slightly modified version to use the credentials from the IAM profile assigned to the EC2 instance.  I also didn't have xxd available on the machine so a tweaked it to use sed.

```
#!/bin/bash

#### Variables

REGION=eu-west-2
S3_KEY='/some/file.txt'   # The file you want to download
FILENAME=$(basename $S3_KEY)
S3_HOST=yourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com # Endpoint for the S3 bucket


#### Get Temporary AWS Credentials from instance metadata ###### 

ROLE_NAME=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/)
CREDENTIALS_TEXT=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/$ROLE_NAME)

S3_SECRET_KEY=$(echo $CREDENTIALS_TEXT | sed -e 's/.*SecretAccessKey" : "\(.*\)", "Token.*/\1/')
S3_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $CREDENTIALS_TEXT | sed -e 's/.*AccessKeyId" : "\(.*\)", "SecretAccessKey.*/\1/')
TOKEN=$(echo $CREDENTIALS_TEXT | sed -e 's/.*Token" : "\(.*\)", "Expiration.*/\1/')

####################################

##### Create the string that needs signing ########

AMZ_DATE=$(date -u "+%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
DATE=$(/bin/echo ${AMZ_DATE} | cut -b 1-8)

CANONICAL_REQUEST="GET\n${S3_KEY}\n\nhost:${S3_HOST}\nx-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD\nx-amz-date:${AMZ_DATE}\nx-amz-security-token:${TOKEN}\n\nhost;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token\nUNSIGNED-PAYLOAD"
STRING_TO_SIGN="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n${AMZ_DATE}\n${DATE}/${REGION}/s3/aws4_request\n$(/bin/echo -en ${CANONICAL_REQUEST} | sha256sum | cut -f 1 -d' ')"

####################################

#### Use Temporary AWS Credentials to create signing key ###### 

AWS_SIG_V4_AND_S3_SECRET_KEY=AWS4${S3_SECRET_KEY}

DATE_HMAC_HEX=$(/bin/echo -n "${DATE}" | openssl sha256 -hmac "${AWS_SIG_V4_AND_S3_SECRET_KEY}" | cut -f 2 -d' ')
DATE_HMAC_BIN=$(/bin/echo -n "${DATE_HMAC_HEX}" | sed 's/\([0-9A-F]\{2\}\)/\\\\\\x\1/gI' | xargs printf)

REGION_HMAC_HEX=$(/bin/echo -n "${REGION}"  | openssl sha256 -hmac "${DATE_HMAC_BIN}" | cut -f 2 -d' ')
REGION_HMAC_BIN=$(/bin/echo -n "${REGION_HMAC_HEX}" | sed 's/\([0-9A-F]\{2\}\)/\\\\\\x\1/gI' | xargs printf)

SERVICE_HMAC_HEX=$(/bin/echo -n "s3"  | openssl sha256 -hmac "${REGION_HMAC_BIN}" | cut -f 2 -d' ')
SERVICE_HMAC_BIN=$(/bin/echo -n "${SERVICE_HMAC_HEX}" | sed 's/\([0-9A-F]\{2\}\)/\\\\\\x\1/gI' | xargs printf)

SIGNING_KEY_HEX=$(/bin/echo -n "aws4_request"  | openssl sha256 -hmac "${SERVICE_HMAC_BIN}" | cut -f 2 -d' ')
SIGNING_KEY_BIN=$(/bin/echo -n "${SIGNING_KEY_HEX}" | sed 's/\([0-9A-F]\{2\}\)/\\\\\\x\1/gI' | xargs printf)

####################################

#### Sign string with signing key ## 

SIGNATURE_HEX=$(/bin/echo -ne "${STRING_TO_SIGN}" | openssl sha256 -hmac "${SIGNING_KEY_BIN}" | cut -f 2 -d' ')

####################################

#### Put it all together into a curl request ## 

curl https://${S3_HOST}${S3_KEY} \
    -H "Host: ${S3_HOST}" \
    -H "x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD" \
    -H "x-amz-date: ${AMZ_DATE}" \
    -H "X-Amz-Security-Token: ${TOKEN}" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${S3_ACCESS_KEY}/${DATE}/${REGION}/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;X-Amz-Security-Token,Signature=${SIGNATURE_HEX}" -o $FILENAME

####################################
```

Comment: Interesting. I did some tests with this script and it has a few moments that it stops working(returns 403 - Forbidden). Then you have to wait a while to try again.